# Ambiguous use of subscript in an init

Tags: swift

I'd just get an issue with a init in a new object Weather I created from http://openweathermap.org/api. My project worked well with a simulator in Xcode but when I wanted to put my application in my smartphone, I just get a fatal issue. 
When it built, it says that I made a Ambiguous use of subscript.

Here is the part of the code I used from a tutorial :

```
init(weatherData: [String: AnyObject]) {

    city = weatherData["name"] as! String

    let coordDict = weatherData["coord"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    longitude = coordDict["lon"] as! Double
    latitude = coordDict["lat"] as! Double

    let weatherDict = weatherData["weather"]![0] as! [String: AnyObject] // Error came here.
    weatherID = weatherDict["id"] as! Int
    mainWeather = weatherDict["main"] as! String
    weatherDescription = weatherDict["description"] as! String
    weatherIconID = weatherDict["icon"] as! String

    let mainDict = weatherData["main"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    temp = mainDict["temp"] as! Double
    humidity = mainDict["humidity"] as! Int
    pressure = mainDict["pressure"] as! Int

    cloudCover = weatherData["clouds"]!["all"] as! Int

    let windDict = weatherData["wind"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    windSpeed = windDict["speed"] as! Double
    windDirection = windDict["deg"] as? Double

    if weatherData["rain"] != nil {
        let rainDict = weatherData["rain"] as! [String: AnyObject]
        rainfallInLast3Hours = rainDict["3h"] as? Double
    }
    else {
        rainfallInLast3Hours = nil
    }

    let sysDict = weatherData["sys"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    country = sysDict["country"] as! String
    sunrise = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: sysDict["sunrise"] as! NSTimeInterval)
    sunset = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:sysDict["sunset"] as! NSTimeInterval)
}
```

This code extract values from a Dict imported from the weather API.

Have any idea of a solution ?

Thank for all.

Answer (score 2):

Do one more step to specify the type of `weather` as an array of dictionaries

```
let weather = weatherData["weather"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
let weatherDict = weather[0]
```

because the compiler does not exactly know if `weather` is an array (index subscripted) or dictionary (key subscripted). That's the ambiguity.

PS: A better syntax (aside from all forced unwrapped optionals) is

```
if let rainDict = weatherData["rain"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
    rainfallInLast3Hours = rainDict["3h"] as? Double
} else {
    rainfallInLast3Hours = nil
}
```

Comment: Worked great ! Thanks. Do you know why this issue came out ? I don't understand how it worked (by making 2 steps of declaration instead of 1 :) ). Thank you again :)

Comment: I edited the answer to add an explanation. The value for a key in a dictionary is always `AnyObject` (is an object but could be anything), so the compiler needs more information about the actual type.

Comment: Oh okay, didn't know this specification. Thanks